# ¿Flutter in_app_purchase 0.5.1 con el test de tarjeta lenta rechazada retorna verdadero?

Tags: flutter, dart, pago-in-app

en esta ocasión cuando desarrollo mi app en Flutter utilizando el paquete [in_app_purchase 0.5.1](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) las compras en la app funcionan perfectamente en el modo de test siempre y cuando no sean con "slow test card", hay alguna solución a este problema, el código es exactamente igual que el ejemplo que muestran en la página web sin ningún cambio, pero al probar con slow test card en modo rechazado se queda cargando mostrando un CircularProgressIndicator() eternamente. Y al cerrar y volver a abrir me aparece como si lo hubiera comprado con el check.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

seria mas facil que dieras un poco mas de contexto, habilitaste las configuraciones de purchases en https://developer.android.com, si puedes compartir que version de flutter y dart estas utilizando y la version de ese package.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](/help/privileges) podrás dejar comentarios en las preguntas para pedir aclaraciones al autor. Lee [answer].